# Change URL with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Now I'm changing urls with the code below; I'm now using also also a url like

```
profile.php?id=Nickname
```

Now I just want to access it only with Nickname

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+) profile.php?id=$1
```

Your version won't work, since the variable you're rewriting will always be `profile`, if the original url is `profile.php?id=Nickname`.